# law for a random variable

Tags: digital-communications

Let: $Y=|X_1+X_2|^2$ with $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. $X_1,X_2$ are independent complex random variables. Consequently, $Y=Re(X_1+X_2)^2+Im(X_1+X_2)^2$

My question:
Does Y follow a Rice law? I know that $Re(X_1+X_2)$ and $Im(X_1+X_2)$ follow gausian law.

Comment: Z? hard to tell

Comment: At least use $\mathcal{CN}$ or $\mathbb{CN}$ to give people a hint that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _complex Gaussian_ instead of the plain real random variables suggested by $N(\mu_1, \sigma_i^2)$